# How to use a column with values that are duplicates to compare against another column in a row wise manner and combine values in new column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

```
TABLE
Description        ID          Column
Tail               61b         Head_Tail
Head               61b         Head_Tail
Head               42g         Head
Tail               86r         Tail
Head               72p         Head_Tail
Tail               72p         Head_Tail
```

The 'Column' is what the output I desire is

So far:

I have

```
Column = SWITCH(
TRUE(),
'TABLE'[ID] = CONTAINSSTING('TABLE'[Description],"Head"), "Head",
'TABLE'[ID] = CONTAINSSTING('TABLE'[Description],"Tail"), "Tail",
(Don't know where to go for comparing 2 columns where 1 column has same values),
BLANK())
```

Comment: or is GROUPBY() applicable in side of SWITCH()??

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem in power query with the following M-Code. Maybe it is better to do that in PowerQuery because if you add other Descriptions it will automatacally use the new Description without changing any DAX-Code.

The Source table in this example is named "tbl_Konsama"

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbl_Konsama"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Description", type text}, {"ID", type text}}),
    GroupedRows_by_ID = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"GroupedRows", each _, type table [Description=text, ID=text
]}}),
    AddedCustomCol_List_with_Description = Table.AddColumn(GroupedRows_by_ID, "Column", each List.Sort([GroupedRows][Description], Order.Ascending)),
    Expanded_GroupedRows = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddedCustomCol_List_with_Description, "GroupedRows", {"Description"}, {"Description"}),
    Extracted_List_in_Column = Table.TransformColumns(Expanded_GroupedRows, {"Column", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "_"), type text})
in
    Extracted_List_in_Column
```

[image]

Comment: That was an awesome answer! My source is a query made from a different excel file, the query was transformed to this point, I'm assuming that the steps should still work. I'm excited to try it out!!